# (Gintama) Which historical period is the Amanto invasion a reference to?

Tags: gintama

I've left uni ages ago and haven't had a History of Japan class since. The Amanto/aliens are clearly references to Americans, and more broadly, to the outside world/western world entering the tightly closed world that was Japan, but I can't pin point exactly which real life historical period the anti-foreigner war is supposed to reference: is it when Americans forced Japan out of the sakoku in the 1800s or after Americans installed a new government in Japan after WW2? I know that both events were resented by Japanese people, so the resentment alone present in Gintama makes it confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure it's the time when Matthew Perry force open Japan in 1853. The way the samurais was forced to abandon their swords is similar to that of what happened in the Meiji era. The setting is also Edo period, which means that the WW2 theory can be ruled out

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a source on this but it definitely seems like it's inspired from America's occupation of Japan post WW2.